# Changing the value of a SQL table with inserts into an other table

Tags: sql, database, create-table, insert-statement

For example:

1. Table: `Bankaccount`, with an `id` as primary key and a value.
2. Table: `Category`, with an `id` as primary key, a name and a type (boolean, 0 for positive transactions and 1 for negative)
3. Table: `Transaction`, with an `id` as primary key, a value (for example -10000$ for shopping) and a foreign key which references `Category`.

My question is if it's possible to add some transactions to the `Transaction` table, which causes the automatic change of the value in the `Bankaccount` table.

I hope someone of you could help me there!

Comment: You may want to look at [triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)

Comment: is the value in Bankaccount the sum (per id) of transaction.value for the same id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use triggers: an after insert trigger
Something like this (syntax depends on the used dbms):

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trg_transaction
AFTER INSERT
   ON ***transaction***

DECLARE
   -- variable declarations

BEGIN
   -- trigger code
   UPDATE ***bankaccount*** SET ....

END;
```

Hope this will help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what I was searching for, thank you very much! I just tried it on a H2-Database and don't know what I did wrong, maybe you could help me there too. My trigger looks like this:

```
create trigger transaction_trig_value_ai after isert of value on transaction
declare
v_value double;
v_type_category boolean;
cursor c_value IS SELECT  value from transaction where id = :NEW.idcategory;
cursor c_type_kategorie IS SELECT type from category where id = :NEW.idcategory;
begin
open c_value;
fetch c_value into v_value;
close c_value;
open c_type_category;
fetch c_type_category into v_type_category;
close c_type_category;

if v_type_category == 0 then
update bankaccount
set value = value +  v_value;
end if;
if v_type_category == 1 then
update bankaccount
set value = value - v_value;
end if;
```

Comment: Hi,
First, I don't think thant you must use cursor in this case.
But, in the update statment of bankaccount table, where is the "WHERE" in this sql command???